# Finding oscillation frequency in a harmonic polluted signal

Tags: fft, frequency, estimation, pll

I would like to find periodicity and the oscillation frequency in a signal. I used this simple MATLAB code which works find for some signals, but for a harmonic polluted signal like the one given below it generates wrong results. Is there any way to estimate the frequency of oscillation for a signal like the one given here. I appreciate any MATLAB code snippets.

I wonder if there is a simple way of using fft to estimate the fundamental oscillation frequency or using an FLL frequency estimator.

```
[pks,pktimes] = findpeaks(x, (1:N)*DT);
Period = mean(diff(pktimes))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  This question, or a variant of it, crops up quite a bit.  Please have a search for "period" or "periodic" and see if any of those help. If not, please edit your question with what's missing from what you need and I'll reopen for answers.

Comment: Have you tried the methods described in the linked answer (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15114/cant-find-out-the-period-of-my-signal)? If they do not work, please edit your question to explain how they fail.